# Re executing a code after a certain period of time in android

Tags: java, android

I am in a google map project and here is my code in oncreate:

```
mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setSatellite(false);
        mapView.setStreetView(true);
        mapController = mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(19);
        getLastLocation();
        drawCurrPositionOverlay();
        drawMalls();
        animateToCurrentLocation();
```

but now i want to call this DrawMalls(); method after some seconds and unless the user closes this application this method will be being called after that time? Is there any way to do this?

Comment: There may be some library methods, but manually you can do it using System.currenttimeMillis()

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and [`Runnable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) combination to execute statements after a period of time.

You can delay a Runnable using [postDelayed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) method of Handler.

```
Runnable mRunnable;
Handler mHandler=new Handler();

mRunnable=new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 drawMalls();
                 //If you want to re call this method at a gap of x seconds then you can schedule  handler again
                  mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable,2*1000);       
                }
            };
mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable,10*1000);//Execute after 10 Seconds
```

If you want to cancel this then you have to use [removeCallback()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method of Handler like  `mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);`

Or You can use Timer. You can refer an example here http://thedevelopersinfo.wordpress.com/2009/10/18/scheduling-a-timer-task-to-run-repeatedly/

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `java.util.Timer`'s `schedule()` method to arrange future execution of `drawMalls()`:

```
Timer t = new Timer();

t.schedule(
    new TimerTask()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            System.out.println("hello\n");
        }
    },
    2000); // Milliseconds: 2 * 1000
```

I am unsure if `drawMalls()` is a `static` or non-static method. If it is `static` then it is straightforward to call in the `TimerTask.run()` method. Otherwise, you will need to arrange for the class instance to which `drawMalls()` belongs is available to the `run()` method of `TimerTask`:

```
class DrawMallsTask extends TimerTask
{
    public DrawMallsTask(YourClass a_build) { _instance = a_instance; }

    public void run() { _instance.DrawMalls(); }

    private YourClass _instance;
};

Timer t = new Timer();

t.schedule(new DrawMallsTask(this), 2000);
```

EDIT:

To repeatedly run the task after every two seconds you can use:

```
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new DrawMallsTask(this), 2000, 2000);
```

Comment: How can I do this? can u give me an example?

Comment: your code works fine, but i want to run this code after every two seconds, then what to do?

Comment: Thank you very much, its working, can you help me another one? In this code i am redrawing some points after every 2seconds, but i want to remove the previous points, what shoould I do?

Comment: No problem. If that solves this current problem Sabbir you should accept this answer (only if there are no others that you prefer) and open a new question with the new problem: more people will see it and be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the instructions for using a ScheduledExecutorService [here](http://0xcafebabe.wordpress.com/2012/01/14/coding-gems-gem-2-simple-scheduling/) I've had bugs before where timer's wouldn't be stopped and started properly on 2.1, the scheduling scheme described worked perfectly for me though.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways

1) using Handler
2)Using Timer

```
      //using Timer//
    public void OnCreate(Bundle SaveInstanceState())
    {
      ------------
      -----------------
      PreferedTime  pTime=new preferedTime();

      Timer t=new Timer(false);
      t.Schedule(pTime,2000);
   }


   class PreferedTime extends TimerTask
   {
      public void run()
      {
         drawMalls();
       }
   }




     //method 2//
     public void OnCreate(Bundle SaveInstanceState())
    {
      -----------------
      -----------------
     Handler handler=new handler(new Runnable()
     {
        public void run()
        {
            drawMalls();
         }
      },2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MyCount counter;
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
 counter= new MyCount(60000,1000);
counter.start();
}    


public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{
public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
}
@Override
public void onFinish() {
 counter= new MyCount(60000,1000);
}
@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    s1=millisUntilFinished/1000;
 if(s1%2==0)
{
drawMalls();

}


}
}
```

this one calls drawMalls() for every 2 seconds..u can change it as required..

Answer (score 0):

If re-executing code is not bound to state of application, but only to time period, look at `Timer` class

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

```
Timer timer;

function myCallerFunction(){
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(seconds * 1000); //must be in milliseconds
}

private class MyTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
      drawMalls();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to prevent execution of this Task when the app stops before reaching the timeout.